# Magento 1.9 extension obsolete in Magento 2.0?

Tags: migration

I have many extensions that provided extended features in Magento 1.9. I would like to that the leap and migrate to Magento 2. Question: have some of these extensions become obsolete in Magento 2.0. In other words could simple configuration or simple modifications provide me with the same features in Magento 2.0?

1. Call For Price
2. ElasticSearch
3. Product price per customer
4. Ability to add a custom carrier, i.e. Free Local Delivery
5. One Step Checkout
6. Rich snippets
7. SEO capabilities, i.e. add Product Description, canonical url
8. List item
9. Banners
10. Advanced CMS page editing
11. AMP

Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Magento 1 extensions are **not** compatible with Magento 2.

You may find that the authors of your Magento 1 extensions have developed Magento 2 versions or that some features provided by your Magento 1 extensions i.e. Elasticsearch are now built into Magento 2.

Go through each extension and check with the original author if they have developed an equivalent Magento 2 version, or check online for other Magento 2 modules that implement the functionality you require.